# Facebook always reauthorizing on each app launch?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have recently added Facebook integration to my app, and everything works fine except when the user relaunches the app. Each time the app is restarted, Facebook has to go back through its authorization process. This involves switching out of the app to Safari/Facebook, then back to my app. How can I make Facebook save the info, or be able to get blanket permissions for my app so that I doesn't constantly reauthorize?

Here is my code from the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"203604286395694" andDelegate:self];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}
```

Relevant Facebook delegate methods:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

- (void) requestDialogButtonClicked {
    NSMutableDictionary* params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"invites you to check out cool stuff",  @"message",
     @"Check this out", @"notification_text",
     nil];  
    [facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {
    NSLog(@"dialog completed successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling Facebook authorize: somewhere?  That's how the fbDidLogin will be triggered.  Assuming you are, the behavior indicates that either the token or the date (or both) is nil, or that the date is past expiration (unlikely).

Log the values upon writing and reading the user defaults.  My guess is that the authorize either wasn't called, or failed (due to app key or some other problem not shown in the code), leaving the fbDidLogin method uncalled or saving nil values.

Comment: Authorize is being called with non-nil values. However, `fbDidLogon` is never getting called. I put a breakpoint at both the authorize call and the fbDidLogon method, but the second one is not hit after the first is.

Comment: see @Malek_Jundi 's comment.  You must be getting the error callback.  Implement that didNotLogin method and NSLog there.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not asking for permissions when you authorize your app .. "offline_access" provide a long term access token so you will not need to get a new access token every time the user wants to use the Facebook .. so what you need to authorize your app like this

```
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            @"user_likes", 
            @"read_stream",
            @"offline_access"
            nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];
}
```

**Edit :** 
Please check the following in your implementation :

1.you need to add the following functions in your application delegate(the Facebook object here is your instance value of FaceBook Class).

```
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
   return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
   return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

2.In your info.plist add to URL types > URL Schemes > your Facebook app ID with fb prefix (finally your value will be like this for ex. fb313714***).

Comment: I added the code you suggested, but no luck. The user doesn't have to actually have to re-allow access, all that happens is that my app switches to Facebook, and after a short load, immediately switches back.

Comment: this is weird ! are you sure that `fbDidLogin` is being called ?

Comment: No, it isn't. It should be called after `authorize` is called right?

Comment: yes .. so your problem is here your app is never been authorized ! because of that its open the fb every time , ok check this method if it is being called `- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;`

Comment: It is! What does that mean implementation wise?

Comment: its mean there is an error with authorization , ok did you handle open the fb url in your app delegate ?

Comment: I fixed the problem by disabling the app/Safari logon. Now, the user logs in via a dialog box and there is no issue with fbDidLogin. Why would this change the behavior?

Comment: unfortunately we can't define the error with safari logon .. but if you follow the steps I wrote above the SSO login should work !